# How are the RIB entry BGP attributes represented according to RFC6396 (MRT Routing Information Export Format)

Tags: bgp, standardisation

The [RFC6396](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6396#page-12) specifies the header for RIB-entry mrt-records like this:

```
        0                   1                   2                   3
        0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1
       +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
       |         Peer Index            |
       +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
       |                         Originated Time                       |
       +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
       |      Attribute Length         |
       +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
       |                    BGP Attributes... (variable)
       +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
```

But the textual explanation ([link](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6396#page-12)) does not specify how and in which order the BGP Attributes have to appear. Assuming that they mean path attributes of the [BGP-4 standard](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4271#page-23).

**How and in which order are the BGP attributes to be represented to be consistent with RFC6396 (Multi-Threaded Routing Toolkit (MRT) Routing Information Export Format)?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out the attributes are encoded the same way [RFC4271(BGP-4)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4271#page-23) specifies them. In a previous draft it was even [explicitly stated](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-grow-mrt-13#page-11) but it got somehow dropped in the final version:

> ...the BGP path attribute length and attributes encoded as provided in a BGP Update message.

Each path attribute is therefore a triple `<attribute type, attribute length, attribute value>` of variable length and its exact layout/specs can be read at the [corresponding RFC](http://www.iana.org/assignments/bgp-parameters/bgp-parameters.xhtml).

Answer (score -2):

I'm guessing it grabs that info from the Update Message, which contains a 2 byte Path Attribute Section.

Comment: as this RFC is on standard-track I was hoping for another RFC or author comment on how to do it. Further is your answer in this wording wrong or at least misleading as an attribute is a triple <type,length,value> where the first two elements alone are 3-4 byte. (Not mentioning possible other listed attributes)

Comment: Wow, there are other ways to express the same. I was trying to help.